# It is possible to enable CORS in an old Windows GeoServer version (2.6.1) using Jetty 6.1.8?

Tags: geoserver, cors, jetty

Of course I found some info about how I have to do this. But I cannot find the jetty-servlet package matching this old version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, but it would be much easier to upgrade to a modern version of both Jetty and GeoServer.

Comment: You're right. This is the best solution.